# iframes created by an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a rather simple question: If an extension creates an iframe and attaches it to the DOM, will the iframe trigger all extension files with `run_at` set to `document_start` to be injected? Basically, are iframes created by extensions given the exact same treatment as iframes created by the page's scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no matter what makes the change, creating an `<iframe>` creates a new `document` and all new `document`s are compared against all Chrome Extension manifests.